# How avoid Restarting of Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on Fragments. I am using Navigation Drawer(Sliding Menu) with Action Bar activity.

Navigation Drawer having 4 menu items.Each Menu Item has Separate Fragment like:

Fragment 1,Fragment 2,Fragment 3, Fragment 4.

By default Fragment 1 will be opened. Based on the selection from the menu particular fragment screen will be opened.

If we are opening a same fragment again the fragment is restarting.So here my problem is **fragment should not be restarted as it opened again**.

I don't have much idea about fragments whether it is possible to **avoid restarting the fragment** when we are not opening it first time.
      So can any body help whether it is possible or not?

Comment: Yes , if i understand you , i used some stack method for fragment , you may read about it , i know its a bit different , but have a read first http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#BackStack

Comment: Hi Leon--I gone through the above link,there fragments are stored in back stack.So When ever we clicks back previous fragment is opening.But here also that previous fragment restarting.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid restarting fragment? resuming its state is natural part of its lifecycle, so it will always be resumed after being hidden. Could you explain a little more what you are doing?